# What is a good script language for writing server administration tasks?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, scripting

I am administering hundreds of RHEL servers. There are many daily tasks to perform. Right now I am working with bash scripting and python. I was wondering if other languages such as Erlang, Lua, Ruby, Haskell, or Clojure.

Comment: Bash and python are both good. What features are you missing?

Comment: http://k1024.org/~iusty/papers/icfp10-haskell-reagent.pdf document about google's experience trying haskell over python for sys-admin tools, they were quite pleased with the results. Even released the resultant tools as ganeti-htools ca. 2009, and I can say that currently the haskell ecosystem has made leaps and bounds in maturity over the past 4 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since bash and python have already been recommended, I'd recommend Ruby.

Two very handy tools come to mind: [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) and [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano).

Rake allows you to have tasks. A task is, for example, a list of commands to execute. Or it can be way more complex and include code. A lot already exist, there are plenty of libraries, and defining a new task is relatively easy.

capistrano (based on Rake syntax) allows you to have tasks, just like Rake, but by including remote tasks by default. From the description:

> Capistrano is a utility and framework for executing commands in parallel on multiple remote machines, via SSH. It uses a simple DSL (borrowed in part from Rake) that allows you to define tasks, which may be applied to machines in certain roles. It also supports tunneling connections via some gateway machine to allow operations to be performed behind VPN's and firewalls.

Not to mention that the Ruby language was invented to remain simple.

> A dynamic, interpreted, open source programming language with a focus on simplicity and productivity.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your needs and preference.

Generally, I find that **bash** is the most important. There are some tasks which can get a bit ugly with it, though, in which case **Python** is my only choice.

Why? Because it's not as ugly as **Perl**, and has the greatest library availability after it.